# Apache and MySQL inside XAMPP Failing to Start

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, server

This is the error I am receiving:

[image: XAMPP Window Error]

Here is the error log; http://pastebin.com/zxKeFAJJ

I do not have skype installed and I have changed the ports. I have XAMPP installed on an external HDD.

Comment: its possible if xampp port config

Comment: "I do not have skype installed and I have changed the ports."Thanks for the reply but I have already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know I just asked this question, but I found the answer, hopefully it can save some people time in the future;

### locate to the XAMPP directory and start the setup_xampp.bat file to refresh the install and reset all the configs. Really simple and fast to do.

If changing the ports doesn't work for you, try this method as it could be an installation or drive problem. Thanks!